# How can i push_back ShortBuffer data in std::vector<short>?

Tags: c++

I have data in the `ShortBuffer` variable.

I want to `push_back` in the `std::vector<short>` `input` variable. I have used the following code, but because of the long for loop the apps freeze.

Is there another way to do it?

```
ShortBuffer *pBuffer1 = pData->AsShortBufferN();

std::vector<short> input(BUFFER_SIZE);

for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE-1; ++i) {
    short out1;
    pBuffer1->Get(out1);
    input.push_back(out1);
}
```

Comment: What is `ShortBuffer`?

Comment: ShortBuffer means one type of ByteBuffer.. it stores the short dataType..

Comment: Can you post the definition of `ShortBuffer` ?

Comment: ShortBuffer means* Creates a new @c short buffer view for the content of the byte buffer.

Comment: @Sunnyshah And what? We should see definition of ShortBuffer, or ByteBuffer.

Comment: It does not matter how often you repeat the description, can you post the definition of it? It appears to a `class` or `struct`. With the definition, people can provide a more useful answer.

Comment: Allocate a new short array and create a buffer based on it;

Comment: @Sunnyshah: `ShortBuffer` is not a standard type, so without seeing its definition (that is, the actual class definition specifying its members, not a description of it) we have no way to know how to use it. Could you please post its definition?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, this is apparently it: http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1ByteBuffer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ShortBuffer` is [what I think it is](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1ByteBuffer.html), this should work:

```
// Allocate enough space to avoid push_back
std::vector<short> input(BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
// Let the GetArray method do the copying
pBuffer1->GetArray(&input[0], 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
```